# Editing Stripe invoice line item descriptions

Tags: stripe-payments

My employer has just had a customer be confused by the invoice e-mail sent by Stripe upon a recurring subscription charge with prorated items:

```
Unused time on Silver plan after 27 Aug 2015      -$48.13
Remaining time on Gold plan after 27 Aug 2015     $240.63
Subscription to Gold plan                         $250.00
```

She thought she was being charged for an extra month somehow. We'd really like to make it more obvious what these charges mean, for example by specifying the exact time period each item applies to - something like what Stripe shows in its dashboard:

```
Unused time on Silver plan    Aug 27, 2015 — Sep 26, 2015    -$48.13
Remaining time on Gold plan   Aug 27, 2015 — Sep 26, 2015    $240.63
Subscription to Gold plan     Sep 26, 2015 — Oct 26, 2015    $250.00
```

However, I see no way to customize Stripe's invoice e-mails beyond the header, and while we could edit the description of the proration invoice items in a webhook callback, I don't see a way to edit the description of the subscription item. According to the [API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#invoice_line_item_object), the id of a line item is just either an invoice item ID or a subscription ID, so the line item itself can't be retrieved or edited directly, and I don't want to edit the description of the subscription itself, just of the item on this one invoice.

Is the only way to do this to send our own invoices from scratch and not use Stripe's invoicing at all, or is there some way I haven't discovered?

Comment: Would like to know the exact same thing! Did you manage to find anything to edit invoice line items?

Comment: Is not changing the description basically what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Directly updating the text of these automatically created line items is not supported. Instead, if you'd like to exert more control over this when updating a subscription, you can disable proration with `proration_behavior=none` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior), [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations#disable-prorations)) and optional add your own line item with `add_invoice_items` ([API ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-add_invoice_items)).

Note that `add_invoice_items` only supports *positive* amounts, so for downgrades you would need to either allow the proration or consider using [Credit Notes](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/credit-notes) or [Customer balance](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance) adjustments.